# Dynamically restrict hibernate-search query with fixed value.

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I'm wondering how to go about restricting a hibernate-search query with a fixed value, example, if I'm doing a free text search against an electronics store where they have a value in the URL restricting the results to computer only. Or another example may be to do a search based on location.

Current Code

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class Store {

   @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
   private String name;

   @IndexedEmbedded
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "computer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
   private List<Computer> computers;
}

@Entity
public class Computer {

   @Field
   private String name;

   @ContainedIn
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "store_id", nullable = false)
   private Store Store;
}
```

Keyword Search Query

```
FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(sessionManager.getSession());
        QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Store.class).get();
        Query luceneQuery = queryBuilder.keyword().onFields("name").andField("computers.name").matching(keyword).createQuery();

        org.hibernate.search.FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Computer.class);
```

Does anybody know what I'm missing to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the proper way to restrict a hibernate-search query would be done using .bool() like so.

```
String store = "Orlando Electronics";

Query luceneQuery = queryBuilder.bool()
                .should(queryBuilder.keyword().onFields("name").matching(store).createQuery())
                .must(queryBuilder.keyword().onFields("computers.name").matching("Dell").createQuery())
                .createQuery();
```

Could someone please comment letting me know if I'm on the right track?